# Assign multidimensional array to DataGridView in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, datagridview

I want to assign 2D array to DataGridView.

There are 2 buttons, the first is an array button which will add my inputs to the array every time I press it.

The second button is a submit button that will assign all of the values of the array to the DataGridView.

But I just can't work it out, every time I press the array button, the value is replaced by the new value I inputted.

Here's the code:

```
Public Class Form2
Dim array(1, 4) As String

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    For i = 0 To array.GetUpperBound(0)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(array(i, 0), array(i, 1), array(i, 2), array(i, 3))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnArray_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnArray.Click
    ReDim array(1, 2)

    Dim id, name As String
    id = txtID.Text
    name = txtName.Text

    For i = 0 To array.GetUpperBound(0)
        array(i, 0) = id
        array(i, 1) = name
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I think this is part of your problem `ReDim array(1, 2)` all that is doing is just changing it from a 1 by 4 dimension to a 1 by 2 dimension. The next problem is that you are just overwriting with the for loop not adding a new dimension to the array. Here is what you need to do. change `ReDim array(1, 2)` to `ReDim array(array.GetUpperBound(0) + 2, 4)` take out the for loop and just put ` array(array.GetUpperBound(0) , 0) = id` and `array(array.GetUpperBound(0) , 1) = name` [here is the redim reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx)

Comment: Forgot the `Preserve` on the `redim` so it should be `ReDim Preserve array(array.GetUpperBound(0) + 2, 4)` not `ReDim array(array.GetUpperBound(0) + 2, 4)`

Comment: @jagler I tried it, but when I clicked the array button, there's an error in the ReDim Preserve array(array.GetUpperBound(0) + 2, 4), it said "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArrayTypeMismatchException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.
Additional information: 'ReDim' can only change the rightmost dimension.". Should I change the 2D array to jagged array so I can use the ReDim Preserve?

Comment: personally I would of just used a list of a custom struct. But a jagged array may work. I don't usually use arrays. Plus a list can be converted easily to an array to go into a datagridview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me!

```
Public Class Form2
Dim arrayCopy(10, 1) As String
Dim b As Integer

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    For i = 0 To b - 1
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(arrayCopy(i, 0), arrayCopy(i, 1))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnArray_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnArray.Click
    Dim id, name As String
    id = txtId.Text
    name = txtName.Text
    arrayCopy(b, 0) = id
    arrayCopy(b, 1) = name
    b += 1
End Sub
End Class
```